# In ionic 2 is there any way to detect scroll momentum as an event?

Tags: javascript, ios, typescript, ionic2

I am trying to detect the scroll momentum event, but so far I have had no luck. I am trying somethiing like this:

```
this.scrollHandle.addEventListener('scroll', function(){
    window.requestAnimationFrame(function(){
        //do animation
    });
});
```

However it stops listening when the finger is removed from the screen, so the animation stops until the momentum ends.

This is the behaviour at least on iOS, not sure about android.

Comment: http://iscrolljs.com/ This may be a solution...

Answer (score 0):

You can now use scroll events on your `ion-content` tag like this:

```
<ion-content (ionScroll)="myFunction($event)">
  <!-- PAGE CONTENT -->
</ion-content>
```

The events you can use are `ionScroll`, `ionScrollEnd`, `ionScrollStart`. See the [content docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/content/Content/) for more info.

Hope this helps.